# dynamically load data in django modal for each table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, bootstrap-modal

Okay I have tried asking this question before but I haven't gotten much help and I think its because I've been framing it the wrong way.  So I'm going to give it one more try. Please bear with me as I am still a pretty novice developer.

So here is my problem:

I am passing data from the view into the template as context which is being populated into a table for viewing.  To make it more consolidated and easier to view I am truncating the data in the table.  However, to give the user full access to the data I want to display the full data in modal popup window.  However, the modal is only loading data for the first row in the table and displaying that for every other row in the table.

Here is my template html:

```
{% if data %}
  {% for key, value in data %}
    <tr>
       <td scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}.</td>
       <td>

    <div id="popup">
      <p class="citation" data-hover="{{ value.2 }}">{{ value.1 }}
      <img src='{% static "img/expand-icon2.png" %}' id="expand"></p>
      <a class="article" target="_blank" href={{ value.3 }}>{{ value.2 }}</a>
    </div> 

    </td>
    {% if value.4 %}
    <td class='test'>{{ value.4 }}<a href='#' id="trigger_{{ forloop.counter }}"><img src='{% static "img/expand-icon2.png" %}' id="expand"></a>
        {% if methods %}
        {% for key2, value in methods %}{% ifequal key2 key %}
        <div id="classModal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="classInfo" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                ×
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="classModalLabel">
                    Triples:
                    </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table id="classTable" class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th style="width: 4%">#</th>
                    <th>Subject</th>
                    <th>Predicate</th>
                    <th>Object</th>
                    <tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for item in value %}
                        <tr>
                        <td scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}.</td>
                        <td>{{ item }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item }}</td>
                        </tr>

                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">
                Close
                </button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        {% endifequal %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </td>
    {% else %}
    <td>No Provenance Terms Found</td>
    {% endif %}
```

View:

```
od = collections.OrderedDict(reversed(sorted(occoruence_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))))
    od2 = collections.OrderedDict(reversed(sorted(occoruence_dict2.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))))

    od_methods = {}
    od_tools = {}
    od_data = {}
    for key, value in od.iteritems():
        if value[4]:
            od_methods[key] = value[4].split(",")
        if value[5]:
            od_data[key] = value[5].split(",")
        if value[6]:
            od_tools[key] = value[6].split(",")


    context = {

        "title":"Search",
        'data': list(od.iteritems())[:10],
        'tools': od_tools.iteritems(),
        'methods': od_methods.iteritems(),
        'data4': od_data.iteritems(),
        'search_phrase': instanceValuesString,


    }
    return render(request, 'results.html', context)
```

Javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.test').each(function(){
      var trig = '[id^="trigger_"]';
      $(trig).click(function(){
        $('#classModal').modal('show');
        return false;
      })

    });   
  </script>
```

Comment: I think this is not a Django problem. It's about Jquery. I am not an expert in Jquery but I think you should call your Django values into the Jquery. Because the way you did is going to load the first entry of your database.

Comment: I highly recommend you look into a javascript framework to make your life easier. You could use jQuery if you really want. But jQuery was not designed with building a full blown web application in mind. Angular, React would be very useful for you.